# move_uploaded_file from subdomain to root folder

Tags: php, image-uploading, image-upload

I'm trying to use the move_uploaded_file to move an uploaded image from the file input in a subdomain to a folder in the root directory. I can confirm the path is correct because the folder is created but the image is not stored. No errors are return at all. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
$dir="../front-end-assets/".$_POST["location_id"]."/img/articles/".$_POST["article_id"];
if(!file_exists($dir)){
    @mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    @chmod($dir, 0777);
}
$ext=".".pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename=generate_string(10).time().$ext;
move_uploaded_file($filename, $dir."/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

Comment: You're probably not checking for errors or your server isn't setup to catch/display warnings/notices etc. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried and unfortunately no error is returned. I just tried again and it still shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file` movie your file from source to destination. Since your file are store in your temp folder. So instead of using `$filename` you use temp file and make sure your `form element` contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
$ext=".".pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename=generate_string(10).time().$ext;
$tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];// temp path
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dir."/".$filename);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer. I just had to rename the file after it had been stored.